# Passing a value from a checkbox with multiple values using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get the value of a checkbox inside a PHP do while loop, passing the selected item value into a process page (get-mod.php) i am using below code but my console returns `[object NodeList]` any suggestions will help.

My PHP do while loop.

```
$i = 1;

do{ 

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG[]" id="checkboxG'.$i.'" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked" value="'.$row['modelID'].'" /><label for="checkboxG'.$i.'" class="css-label">'.summary($row['model']).'</label><br/>'   ;

$i++;

}while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($c));
```

My ajax code.

```
 $(document).on('change','.css-checkbox',function(){

                      var list = document.getElementsByName('checkboxG[]');
                      console.log("Getting data for "+list);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'get-mod.php',
                data:'getID='+list,
                success:function(html){

                    $('#result1').html(html);

                }
            }); 
        });
```

I am trying to pass the result inside a div with a id of result1, here is my php code (get-mod.php), but for now i just want to return the values of selected checkboxes.

```
$r = $_POST['getID'];

print_r($r);
```

Comment: You should use `$(this)` to get the checkbox that they changed. And don't you need to distinguish whether the box is checked or unchecked?

Comment: Your loop is wrong. It should be a `while` loop, not a `do-while` loop, because you need to fetch the row *before* you put the value into the checkbox.

Comment: If you wrap your checkbox inside one form with specific id , you can get by `$("form-id").serialize()` .That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
var data = { 'getID[]' : []};
$("input:checked").each(function() {
  data['getID[]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

And also

```
data:data,
```

Then print $_POST in PHP file you get all selected data.